# 'greater understanding' without the preceding article 'a'

Tags: expressions, indefinite-article

I'm aware that by default it is ***...a greater understanding***. However, I would like to know if I could leave the indefinite article out in the following case:

**The goal of this programme is simple: better health, greater understanding, deeper connectedness.**

Comment: I would not expect the article in this context, though either possibility works.

Comment: Both **greater understanding** and **deeper connectedness** could be introduced with indefinite articles, but given that these phrases follow **better health** without an article, the sentence certainly reads better without any.

Comment: *Deeper connectedness* sounds a bit odd to me (although there's nothing wrong with it—it's a real word). Personally, I would probably use *deeper connectivity* instead.